# "length(f) == length(.x) is not TRUE" when plotting a bar chart in R

Tags: r

I am plotting a sorted bar chart in R with this code:

```
data %>%
  mutate(channel_name = fct_reorder(channel_name, desc(column_name))) %>%
  ggplot( aes(x=channel_name, y=column_name, tooltip = channel_name)) +
  geom_bar_interactive(stat="identity" )
```

it works fine, but now I would like to set the plotted column dynamically:

```
my_column <- "column_name"
data %>%
  mutate(channel_name = fct_reorder(channel_name, desc(my_column))) %>%
  ggplot( aes(x=channel_name, y=my_column, tooltip = channel_name)) +
  geom_bar_interactive(stat="identity" )
```

but this gives me the error:

```
Error in fct_reorder(channel_name, desc(my_column)) : 
  length(f) == length(.x) is not TRUE
```

what would be the correct syntax?

Comment: use `get(my_column)` ?

Comment: i think you have to use aes_string instead of aes if you whant to pass any argument as string to ggplot: ggplot( aes_string(x="channel_name", y=my_column, tooltip = "channel_name")) and you might also have to adapt the string in mutate by !!sym(my_column)